# jade html escaped string

Tags: html, node.js, escaping, pug

I have a problema with Jade, I take an unescaped string from db (something like this:

`"&lt;mo&gt;&amp"`

this string can contain some html code, I pass the string to the page with

`res.render('page',f(){})`

from the layout I stamp the string with !{t.text} but the html code is not rendered, seems that prints plain text. where is the error?

Comment: what does f() return?  In your jade, you refer to "t.text"  I assume f() returns an object that looks something this: {t: {text: "&lt;mo&gt;&amp"}}


Based on the results, I'm betting t is defined but t.text isn't

Answer (score 0):

1. I've set up default `express` app which uses `jade` as its template engine.
2. Modified `routes -> index.js` to pass some encoded text

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', encodedText: '&lt;mo&gt;&amp' });
});
```

3. Modified `views -> index.jade` to display this text

```html
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  p Encoded text !{encodedText}
```

4. Result seems to be OK

[image]