# Node 5.6.0, Express 4.13.4, Jade 1.11.0 - How to render escaped string as HTML in template

Tags: node.js, pug

A seemingly straightforward question I cannot seem to crack. I am retrieving escaped & sanitized html from a database and I want to unescape it and render it as html in Jade. I have seen this [jade html escaped string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888764/jade-html-escaped-string) question, but the answer is NOT what I want. In the answer to this question the tag is rendered as a string, and NOT as markup. I specifically want the escaped string to be rendered as markup. I have tried the following with the following results.

```
var escapedstring = '&lt;p&gt;Some Textlt;/p&gt;';
```

In Jade...

```
1. div=escapedstring renders <div>&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Some Text&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;</div>
2. div!=escapedstring renders <div>&lt;p&gt;Some Text&lt;/p&gt;</div>

3.div
    !{escapedstring} renders <div>&lt;p&gt;Some Text&lt;/p&gt;</div>

4.div
    #{escapedstring} renders <div>&lt;&lt;p&gt;Some Text&lt;/p&gt;&gt;<!--&lt;p&gt;Head Lease&lt;/p&gt;--></div>
```

Using unescape(escapedstring) produces the same results. Can someone show me what I am doing wrong please?

TIA

Comment: Try this:  `!{escapedstring.replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>')}`

Comment: hi, thanks for this. This does output the correct markup, which is pleasing. I guess my next question would be why doesn't the unescape method do the same thing? Im not sure its practical to append this the end of each bit of escaped html we import, also it doesn't deal with other escaped entities like &quot;. Would you have any insight as to why this works and the unescape method does not? tia

Comment: Jade do not know what in the input string, and the inverse unescape of it he will not. So it is necessary to independently unescape a string or in a router or in a view.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes here, this is what I did. Many thanks to stdob who commented. I have a module called viewhelpers which I add to the locals object globally as a property called vh so that it is available to the jade views. I then npm install a module called html-entities (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities). Then in my viewhelpers I added these two lines..

```
var ent = require('html-entities').XmlEntities;

module.exports.decode = ent.decode;
```

Then in my view I can simply use

```
div!= vh.decode(tenancynote.note)
```

Hope this helps someone.